# Erro ao subir container no docker-compose: `Cannot start service php-fpm: AppArmor...`

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Ele estava funcionando normalmente no meu Ubuntu desde a semana passada, nenhuma atualização foi feita, e agora, quando tento montar contêineres usando o Laradock, obtém isso:

```
$ docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql
Starting laradock_mysql_1 ...
Starting laradock_php-fpm_1 ... error
Starting laradock_mysql_1   ... error
ERROR: for laradock_php-fpm_1  Cannot start service php-fpm: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded.

ERROR: for laradock_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded.

ERROR: for php-fpm  Cannot start service php-fpm: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded.

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Eu procurei na net e não encontrei nada ... Alguém pode me ajudar?